# Dropdown menu with OpenLayers 3

Tags: drop-down-menu, openlayers-3

I am using openlayers 3. From the values contained in a vector GeoJSON, I want to fill a dropdown menu. When selecting a value from the dropdown menu, I want to zoom in on the entity.

My problem now is that I want to generate my HTML from the attributes of my GeoJSON. So I tried this simple code but it doesn't work :

```
var menu = document.getElementById('menuDropDown');
vector2.getSource().forEachFeature(function() {
    menu.innerHTML = feature.get('NOM').join(', ');
  });
```

EDIT:
I'm able to populate a dropdown menu from a list:

```
var list = ['a','b','c'];
var mySelect = $('#mySelect');
    $.each(list, function(val, text) {
        mySelect.append(
            $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
        );
    });
```

What i want to do it's to populate this list from the attribute of my vector
So i try this:

```
// vector2 it's a GeoJSON who is integrate on my map
vector2.getSource().getFeatures().forEachFeature(function(feature) {
    list.push(feature.get('NOM'));
});
```

Comment: Could you explain how this doesn't work? What is the behavior you're expecting and what is actually happening?

Comment: For now, I would expect that Iist all names that are contained in the table of my GeoJSON and from Id 'menuDropDown' I refer in my html and it will be displayed in my popup map interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve my problem:

```
vector2.getSource().on('change', function(evt){
      var source = evt.target;
      var list = [];
        source.forEachFeature(function(feature) {
            list.push(feature.get('NOM')); 
            });
        // console.log("Ecrit moi les noms : " + list);
```

Thanks you to those who took the time to respond

Comment: i wanted to do the same but my layer are published on geoserver. can you help me in this regard? kindly review this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365774/cascading-using-geoserver-and-openlayers?noredirect=1#comment598651_365774

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'm assuming you have to pass some parameter to your callback:

```
vector2.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature) {
```

Then you can append an item to a dropdown like so:

```
var item = document.createElement('option');
item.setAttribute('value', feature.get('NOM'));

var textNode = document.createTextNode(feature.get('NOM'));
item.appendChild(textNode)

menu.appendChild(item);
```

All together:

```
var menu = document.getElementById('menuDropDown');
vector2.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature) {
    var item = document.createElement('option');
    item.setAttribute('value', feature.get('NOM'));

    var textNode = document.createTextNode(feature.get('NOM'));
    item.appendChild(textNode)

    menu.appendChild(item);
});
```

Comment: Interesting like answer, I did not know this method to create the option element. But, i still with no answer in my popup.
vector2 = GeoJSON is a vector that is displayed in my web interface with the NAME attribute in the table.
By the way i'm able to diplay my attribute when i use a select with forEachFeatureAtPixel and the select method

Comment: Jimmie i have edit my post, if you have a way to populate a list from a vector source in openlayers 3. It would be appreciate. Thanks again for you answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. But if you post an example with JSFiddle I will try to help.